# VSCode node js debugger stuck at the structured-stack file

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Currently, I'm running a node js program with the debugger. 
the program uses a lot of promises and using a library called `p-limit`
and I put the debugging config to skip node internal and node modules.

```
"skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
]
```

It's a long running program, it eats cpu and network a lot.
Then I notice the program doesn't eat CPU and network anymore.
So I assume it's stuck and hit the pause button

Somehow the program went stuck at the file called `stuctured-stack`

```
(function() {
    Error.prepareStackTrace = function(err, trace) {
        err.stack = trace;
    };
    Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

    return function structuredStack() {
        return new Error().stack;
    };
})()
```

there's no error thrown and it seems not doing anything

What does this mean?

Edit
Added a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You return the function `structuredStack` but you don't actually call it

Comment: I'm not calling that `structured-stack` function, but somehow when I pressed pause in the debugger it points to that file.

Comment: @otong I am also facing this issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Helpinghand Sorry, I haven't found a solution. I rewrite the script. My guess is because of multiple long running asynchronous task that maybe break but somehow cannot be caught.